# Fix the Lightning component on app page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, salesforce1-app, lightning-design-system

I need to fix the position of 1st component on top & 2nd component at the bottom of page.Both shouldn't be scrollable (As i want them as buttons). If any other component is in between that should only scroll.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can get this out of the box. Try looking at Flexbox, a lot of people have implemented this kind of layout over the years. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47659664/flexbox-with-fixed-header-and-footer-and-scrollable-content/47661523